# Search box within list-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following page:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h3>CAMPAIGNS</h3>
      <!--<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Button</button>-->
    </div>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <p>Sort By</p>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Date
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Date</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-4 pull-right">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aze5uh2h/

When you open the page, you see that the search box is below the Sort By Date. How can I get it to be on the same line?

Comment: @andreivictor I just looked at your fiddle link, but it has the same problem? The search box is still in the row below the Sort By and Date dropdown

Comment: @SimonZhu This ? http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/XdoPGM?editors=1100

Comment: Yeah, I haven't understood very well your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I comment out the "<li>" tag around the search box, the elements fall into a single line. So, if you delete that tag, you should get what you want.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h3>CAMPAIGNS</h3>
      <!--<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Button</button>-->
    </div>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <p>Sort By</p>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Date
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Date</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- li -->
        <div class="input-group col-xs-4 pull-right">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      <!-- /li -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h3>CAMPAIGNS</h3>
    <!--<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Button</button>-->
    </div>
<div class="input-group col-xs-4 pull-right">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <p>Sort By</p>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Date
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Date</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li>

  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lvzMbnVF5c)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read the bootstrap docs to get a better understanding of bootstrap's markup. The following should get you what you're after. https://jsfiddle.net/vsetpLn0/

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h3>CAMPAIGNS</h3>
      <!--<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Button</button>-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        Sort By
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Date <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i dont think the OP wanted a `.00` add-on to their searchbox.. plus your suggested answer extends the search box.  I have created a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7a040Y8zT5) with your suggested answer and you will see what I mean.

Comment: i copied an extra line in there, which has since been removed. And i have updated his search length. You shouldn't just piecemeal out random parts of bootstrap like that. It's best to use the correct markup throughout if you're going to use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.list-inline li:nth-child(3) {
  display: inline;
}
```

Better late than never.